# If a sequence of functions converges in measure to two functions f and g, then f=g almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr M, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N} $ be a sequence of measurable functions. Let $f$ and $g$ be measurable functions such that $\forall \delta > 0$
$$\mu(\{ t : |f_n(t) - f(t) | > \delta\})\to 0$$
$$\mu(\{ t : |f_n(t) - g(t) | > \delta\})\to 0$$
Then is $f=g$ a.e. in $\Omega$? How can I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha>0$. By the triangle inequality one has $$|f(t)-g(t)=|f(t)-f_n(t)+f_n(t)-g(t) \leq |f_n(t)-f(t)|+|f_n(t)-g(t)|.$$ Notice that $$\mu(\{t :|f(t)-g(t)|>\alpha\})\leq \mu(\{t : |f_n(t)-g(t)|>\alpha/2\})+\mu(\{t: |f_n(t)-f(t)|>\alpha/2\}=0+0=0.$$ Hence $\mu(\{t:|f(t)-g(t)>\alpha\})=0$ i.e. $f=g$ a.e. In $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you, I started in that way but I've got stuck trying to prove that $$\{t:|f(t)-g(t)|>\alpha\} \subset \{ t : |f(t)_n - f(t) | > \alpha\} \cup \{ t : |f(t)_n - g(t) | > \alpha\}$$ In order to prove the inequality. Is this the right way? It does not convince me.

Comment: That union comes from the triangle inequality, and it’s $\frac{\alpha}{2}$, not $\alpha$. :)

Comment: Oh, of course, at least one of the two is greater than $\frac{\aplha}{2}$, now it is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f= g$ a.e. fails, then there exists a $c > 0$ and $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ such that $|f-g| > c$ on $E.$